# How to launch AFW badge apps from adb shell command?

Tags: android, shell, android-package-managers, android-for-work

[image]I am unable to launch Android For work enabled apps from Adb shell command?
Can some one plz give example? 
Refer attached screen, I want to launch Playstore app. 
Without badge ICON play store app has the same activity info with the badged playstore app as well(com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity). 
And I am unable to launch the Badge play store activity. Please help me.

I have tried by using below command:
adb shell am start com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity

It is always launching Non-Badged playstore app only.

Then I have tried as per the AFW blog by Google:
https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles.html

> adb shell pm list users
>   UserInfo{0:Drew:13} running
>   UserInfo{10:Work profile:30} running
>
> adb shell am start --user 10 -n "com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER

So, I got the java.lang.SecurityException: Shell does not have permission to access user 10 error. Please someone help me.

Comment: Is your work profile protected by a password? Have you tried calling `adb root` before?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to launch the Apps. 
Make the app in debug mode and add clearUserRestriction of the provision client as below.

```
dpm.clearUserRestriction(adminName,UserManager.DISALLOW_DEBUGGING_FEATURES
```

if we have these changes then I am able to launch the Android For Work badged apps by using the below commands. Where the --user 10 is the AFW Provisioned User.

> adb shell am start --user 10 -n
>   "com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity"
>   -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER